# Update part of page automatically when the data from an object changes without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, page-refresh

I have data being inserted into various divs collected from the backend.
This data gets updated, what i need is for the divs to also automatically update the data within the divs without actually refreshing the whole page.
Right now a page refresh would update the divs but I want the divs to auto update without affecting users experience.
Any suggestions.
As an example, I have a vote up/down button in the frontend, the vote gets sent to the backend then sent back through to the front and inserted into a div, however they wouldnt see their vote registered in the frontend unless they refreshed the page, So I would need the users vote result to be updated in the front end everytime then make a vote or change a vote ect automatically.
This is just one example, there is more data inserted in this table which could be updated at any time.

Update, 
Not sure people understand fully what I need or trying to do. 
Basically have and object coming through from back-end,  on page load, data from that object is inserted into a table such as new posts,  votes ect.

What I need to be able to do is check if the object has changed since the page load and if so to then update the data on the page without refreshing the page.

Ideally need this to happen instantaneously, so it recognises as soon as there is a difference between the object data and that being displayed in the browser and updates it.

Hope that makes it more clear as to what I want to do.

I have and object  with information such as the  suggestiontitle, description, votestatus, etc,  these get inserted into a row, when a new.  A new row gets added when a new object with main object comes through.
So I need to be able to check for changes in the main object so that I can then add the new objects as rows into the table and also Detect and update any changes with current objects already inserted.

Comment: You can use ajax within setInterval of 10sec. It will update your divs in every 10 seconds

Comment: you can try to watch on how to do that on ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, all you want is a way to interact with the backend without refreshing the page, correct? If that's the case, you should look into AJAX. Here's a simple way to use it for the voting system example(requires jQuery):

```
$.post(url_to_interact_with,{key: 1232,vote:1}, function(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

In this case you sent a post request with key=1232 and a vote of 1. The variable in the function (data) is the output of the request.

However, if this isn't such a simple matter for you, I would recommend looking into websockets. To summarize what they are: A back and forth interaction between backend and front end. The back end can send info at any time without refreshing the page. If websockets are too confusing, then use this: https://pusher.com/

But honestly, you shouldn't try to go for the approach of knowing all info of div in real time unless absolutely necessary. Good luck! :)

Comment: No, I already have the data coming from the backend, what i want is for that data being posted to the frontend within a div to be updated if any of the data being received changes, ie a posted voted up, then they should be able to see in the frontend the update once they have voted,

I already have the date being passed through to backend and returned, but the frontend will only update changes if you refresht the page

Comment: Then use pusher or websockets. That's the only way I know that could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I Understood is that you need to update the div whenever Vote is updated? If I understood correctly then I would like to go with delegate and call a function to the server once you get a response from Vote stuff call.

If you want to get an event from the server-side then I would suggest you go for SignalR, for real-time communication, which will give you an event called the server-side.